# SoapUI: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I succeed to test a web service with SoapUI, now I want to add some
condition, my WS accepts the type Long as input, I want to add a condition when 
I enter a String, so I used a block `try catch(NumberFormatException)` and I 
display a message in the log 'invalid number' but always I had the exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException`
in the SoapUI
this is the error in the console :

```
2018-02-26 15:53:51,693 [http-8181-Processor25] INFO  (SoapFaultHandler:113) - java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sss"
```

Test.java

```
try{        
     Long a=new Long(request.getCsId());    
}catch(NumberFormatException nb){   
     LOGGER.debug("invalid number ");   
}
```

SoapUi input :

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <alu:getCustomerStatisticsRequest>
     <alu:csId>sss</alu:csId>
  </alu:getCustomerStatisticsRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SoapUi output:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
   <detail>
      <alu:UnexpectedErrorFault xmlns:alu="http://alu.services.ws.lhs.com">
         <alu:faultcode/>
         <alu:faultstring>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sss"</alu:faultstring>
      </alu:UnexpectedErrorFault>
   </detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Comment: Try using `Long.parseLong(String s)` instead of the Long constructor.

Comment: I used many type of parsing, but I had always `java.lang.NumberFormatException` in SoapUI

Comment: Did you try debugging the request, maybe it's not even going into your try-block?

Comment: Yes I did, I searched for many days in google, I think it's a configuration in SoapUI

Comment: You ws is receiving "sss" which is not a number, am I reading that right?

Comment: Check whether "invalid number " Gets printed in server logs? If it is not that means your Soap handler has interpreted the request and validated against the defined WSDL constraints in this case may be numeric Long. So it would not reach to your app logic.